# Using prosody element with Polly Neural voice in Twilio application generates an error

Tags: c#, twilio-twiml

Using the following code

```cs
var say = new Say("You have a", voice, null, language);
say.Nest(
    new SsmlProsody("great day!", pitch: "+10%")
);
voiceResponse.Append(say);
```

It generates the following response from my TwiML app with a 200 HTTP status code and `Content-Type: application/xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="Polly.Matthew-Neural" language="en-US">You have a
        <prosody pitch="+10%">great day!</prosody>
    </Say>
</Response>
```

But this results in the application creating a generic voice error "We're sorry, an application error has occurred. Goodbye."

I can't see anything wrong with this that should result in an application error.  When I don't use the `prosody` element and just return `<Say voice="Polly.Matthew-Neural" language="en-US">You have a great day!</Say>` It speaks the text as you would expect.  What's up?